# SQL Server get missing records information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I have a question about SQL Server.

If any column does not have values, then need to provide which column does not have a value.

If data is not available in one column, then output column value not available.

If data not available more than one column, then output those columns value are not available.

Concatenate multiple columns when values not exists.

Sample data :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpDetails]
(
    [Empid] [int] NULL,
    [Empname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Location] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Deptid] [int] NULL,
    [Deptname] [varchar](50) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (1, NULL, N'che', 10, N'hr')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (2, N'hari', N'pune', NULL, N'pm')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (3, N'var', NULL, 30, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (4, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'hr')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (NULL, N'venu', N'pune', NULL, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (NULL, N'kumar', N'pune', 20, NULL)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (8, 'ravi', NULL, 10, N'hr')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[EmpDetails] ([Empid], [Empname], [Location], [Deptid], [Deptname]) 
VALUES (10, N'k', N'pune', 20, N'hr')
```

Based on above data I want output like below :

```
empid | Empname | Location | Deptid| Deptname   | Validate
------+---------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------------------------
1     | NULL    |Che       |10     | hr         | Empname value is not available
2     | hari    |pune      |NULL   | pm         | Deptid value is not available
3     | var     |NULL      |30     | NULL       | location and deptname values are not available
4     | NULL    |NULL      |NULL   | hr         | empname and  location and deptid values are not available
NULL  | venu    |pune      |NULL   | NULL       | empid and deptid and deptname values are not available
NULL  | kumar   |pune      |20     | NULL       | empid and deptname values are not available
8     | ravi    |NULL      |10     | hr         | location value is not available
10    | k       |pune      |20     | hr         |
```

I tried like below :

```
SELECT
    empid, empname, location, deptid, deptname,
    CASE 
        WHEN COALESCE(empid, '') = '' THEN 'Empid' 
        ELSE '' 
    END + ' '+
        CASE 
            WHEN COALESCE(empname, '') = '' 
                THEN 'Empname' 
                ELSE '' 
        END + ' '+
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(Location, '') = '' 
                THEN 'Location' 
                ELSE '' 
        END + ' '+
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(Deptid, '') = '' 
                THEN 'Deptid' 
                ELSE '' 
        END + ' '+
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(Deptname, '') = '' 
                THEN 'Deptname' 
                ELSE '' 
        END + ' ' +
        + 'value not available' AS Validate
    FROM 
        [Test].[dbo].[EmpDetails]
```

But this query is not returning the expected output.

Please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Comment: What format does it give?

Comment: validate filed not giving expected format

Comment: If you were on a supported version of SQL Server, `CONCAT_WS` would make this easy. The problem is you are concatenating your white space (`' '`) to your value even if the value was `''`; so you end up with lots of whitespace at the ends.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is based on XML and XQuery.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
(
    Empid int NULL,
    Empname varchar(50) NULL,
    Location varchar(50) NULL,
    Deptid int NULL,
    Deptname varchar(50) NULL
); 
INSERT INTO @tbl (Empid, Empname, Location, Deptid, Deptname) VALUES 
(1, NULL, N'che', 10, N'hr'),
(2, N'hari', N'pune', NULL, N'pm'),
(3, N'var', NULL, 30, NULL),
(4, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'hr'),
(NULL, N'venu', N'pune', NULL, NULL),
(NULL, N'kumar', N'pune', 20, NULL),
(8, 'ravi', NULL, 10, N'hr'),
(10, N'k', N'pune', 20, N'hr');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , s
    , Validate = REPLACE(c.query('
    for $x in /root/source/*
    let $name := local-name($x)
    return if (/root/target/*[local-name(.)=$name]) then ()
    else $name
    ').value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'),SPACE(1), ' and ') + 
    CASE WHEN s=5 THEN ''
        WHEN s=4 THEN ' value is not available'
        WHEN s<4 THEN ' values are not available'
    END 
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><source><Empid/><Empname/><Location/><Deptid/><Deptname/></source>' + 
    (SELECT Empid, Empname, Location, Deptid, Deptname
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('target')) + '</root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('count(/root/target/*)', 'INT')) AS t2(s);
```

**Output**

```
+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Empid | Empname | Location | Deptid | Deptname | s |                         Validate                         |
+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1     | NULL    | che      | 10     | hr       | 4 | Empname value is not available                           |
| 2     | hari    | pune     | NULL   | pm       | 4 | Deptid value is not available                            |
| 3     | var     | NULL     | 30     | NULL     | 3 | Location and Deptname values are not available           |
| 4     | NULL    | NULL     | NULL   | hr       | 2 | Empname and Location and Deptid values are not available |
| NULL  | venu    | pune     | NULL   | NULL     | 2 | Empid and Deptid and Deptname values are not available   |
| NULL  | kumar   | pune     | 20     | NULL     | 3 | Empid and Deptname values are not available              |
| 8     | ravi    | NULL     | 10     | hr       | 4 | Location value is not available                          |
| 10    | k       | pune     | 20     | hr       | 5 |                                                          |
+-------+---------+----------+--------+----------+---+----------------------------------------------------------+
```